# Raycaster malfunctioning in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am creating a game where players can move around from first-person perspective, where the ground is generated with Perlin noise and therefore uneven. I would like to simulate gravity in the game. Hence, a raycasting thing has been implemented, which is supposed to find the player's distance from the ground and stop them from falling when they hit the ground. Here is my code (if the snipper is unclear visit https://3d.211368e.repl.co):

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene(), camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000000000000), renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(), canvas = renderer.domElement; 

camera.rotation.order = "YXZ";

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1);

light.position.set(0, 10000, 0);
light.castShadow = true; 

light.shadow.camera.top = 10000;
light.shadow.camera.right = 10000;
light.shadow.camera.bottom = -10000;
light.shadow.camera.left = -10000;
light.shadow.camera.far = 100000;
wwwww
scene.add(light);

var sky = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(100000, 3, 3, 0, Math.PI, 0, Math.PI), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x579ebb}));

sky.material.side = THREE.BackSide;
sky.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2); 

scene.add(sky);

class Vector2{
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    dot(other){
        return this.x * other.x + this.y * other.y;
    }
}

function Shuffle(tab){
    for(let e = tab.length-1; e > 0; e--){
        let index = Math.round(Math.random() * (e-1)),
            temp  = tab[e];
        
        tab[e] = tab[index];
        tab[index] = temp;
    }
}

function MakePermutation(){
    let P = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        P.push(i);
    }
    Shuffle(P);
    for(let i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        P.push(P[i]);
    }
    
    return P;
}

let P = MakePermutation();

function GetConstantVector(v){
    let h = v & 3;
    if(h == 0) return new Vector2(1.0, 1.0);
    if(h == 1) return new Vector2(-1.0, 1.0);
    if(h == 2) return new Vector2(-1.0, -1.0);
    return new Vector2(1.0, -1.0);
}

function Fade(t){
    return ((6 * t - 15) * t + 10) * t ** 3;
}

function Lerp(t, a1, a2){
    return a1 + t*(a2-a1);
}

function Noise2D(x, y){
    let X = Math.floor(x) & 255;
    let Y = Math.floor(y) & 255;

    let xf = x - Math.floor(x);
    let yf = y - Math.floor(y);

    let topRight = new Vector2(xf - 1, yf - 1);
    let topLeft = new Vector2(xf, yf - 1);
    let bottomRight = new Vector2(xf - 1, yf);
    let bottomLeft = new Vector2(xf, yf);
    
    let valueTopRight = P[P[X+1]+Y+1];
    let valueTopLeft = P[P[X]+Y+1];
    let valueBottomRight = P[P[X+1]+Y];
    let valueBottomLeft = P[P[X]+Y];
    
    let dotTopRight = topRight.dot(GetConstantVector(valueTopRight));
    let dotTopLeft = topLeft.dot(GetConstantVector(valueTopLeft));
    let dotBottomRight = bottomRight.dot(GetConstantVector(valueBottomRight));
    let dotBottomLeft = bottomLeft.dot(GetConstantVector(valueBottomLeft));
    
    let u = Fade(xf);
    let v = Fade(yf);
    
    return Lerp(u, Lerp(v, dotBottomLeft, dotTopLeft), Lerp(v, dotBottomRight, dotTopRight));
}

const plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10000, 10000, 500, 500), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x00aa00}));

plane.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2 + 0.00001); 
plane.receiveShadow = true;
        
for (let y = 0, i = 0; y < 501; y++){
    for(let x = 0; x < 501; x++, i++){
        let n = 0.0, a = 1.0, f = 0.005;
        for (let o = 0; o < 3; o++){
            let v = a*Noise2D(x*f, y*f);
            n += v;
            
            a *= 0.5;
            f *= 2.0;
        }

        n += 1; 
        n /= 2; 

        plane.geometry.vertices[i].z = n * 1000; 
    }
}

scene.add(plane);

const point = plane.geometry.vertices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)]; 

camera.position.set(point.x, point.z + 2, point.y);

const geo = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000})); 
geo.castShadow = true; 

scene.add(geo); 

const render = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    
    const below = new THREE.Vector3(camera.position.x, -1000000, camera.position.y), cast = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, below), intersect = cast.intersectObject(plane);

    if (intersect.length > 0){
        if (intersect[0].distance < 3) camera.translateY(-1);  
    }else{
        camera.translateY(-1); 
    }
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
        
render();

onmousemove = () => {
    if (camera.rotation._x > -0.8 || camera.rotation._y > -0.8){
        camera.rotateX(-Math.atan(event.movementY / 300)); 
        camera.rotateY(-Math.atan(event.movementX / 300)); 
    }else{
        if (Math.atan(event.movementY / 300) < 0) camera.rotateX(-Math.atan(event.movementY / 300)); 
        if (Math.atan(event.movementX / 300) < 0) camera.rotateY(-Math.atan(event.movementX / 300)); 
    }
    camera.rotation.z = 0; 
}

onresize = () => {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth; 
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

onkeydown = (event) => {
    if (event.key == "w") camera.translateZ(-10); 
    if (event.key == "a") camera.translateX(-1); 
    if (event.key == "s") camera.translateZ(1); 
    if (event.key == "d") camera.translateX(1); 
    if (event.key == "ArrowUp") camera.translateY(1); 
    if (event.key == "ArrowDown") camera.translateY(-1); 
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0; 
    background-color: black; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}

canvas{
    border: none; 
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/0949e59f/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/0949e59f/examples/js/utils/SceneUtils.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/0949e59f/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

If the ground is not detected at least 3 units below the camera, the player will continue falling. However, sometimes nothing is spotted below the camera, while the player is clearly hovering over the ground. This is extremely frustrating. Is there any reliable alternative method to solve this problem, such as using something other than raycasting? Or is there a bug in the code? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Raycaster documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster). The constructor takes the origin, the **direction** and near and far parameters. So you could do:

```
const gravityDirection = new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0);
cast = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, gravityDirection, 0, 3);
```

and this also makes the distance check redundant, as the `far` parameter already filters out hits further away than *3* units.

Comment: Nice solution!!! Just change Vector to Vector3 and it works. Thx

Comment: @Newcontributor My bad, fixed :)